# how does tombstones works in android-kernel

Tags: android, linux-kernel, mdm, ramdisk, tombstone

> ```
>    mkdir /data/tombstones 0771 system system
>    symlink /data/tombstones /tombstones
>    mkdir /tombstones/mdm 0771 system system
>    mkdir /tombstones/modem 0771 system system
>    mkdir /tombstones/lpass 0771 system system
>
>    # For firmwares
>    mkdir /firmware_radio 0771 system system
>    mkdir /firmware_q6 0771 system system
>    mkdir /firmware_dsps 0771 system system
>    mkdir /vendor 0771 system system
>    mkdir /vendor/firmware 0771 system system
>
>    devwait emmc@radio
>    mount vfat emmc@radio /firmware_radio ro shortname=lower
>    devwait emmc@adsp
>    mount vfat emmc@adsp /firmware_q6 ro shortname=lower
>
>    exec /system/bin/sh /system/etc/init.qcom.radio_links.sh
>    exec /system/bin/sh /system/etc/init.qcom.q6_links.sh
>
>    mkdir /data/qcks 0770 system system
>    mkdir /data/efs 0771 system system
> ```

How does the mkdir/tombstones/modem works? I have a htc phone where we have our firmware in different partitions but how it grabs them from the partitions without symlinks? I ported 3.4 kernel for my device (we officially got the 3.0.16) in the 3.4 the kickstart and qcks doesnt support through ttyhsl anymore with the rom I'm porting it use this tombstones way..just wondering how it works...the official ramdisk have the images in this format.

```
symlink /vendor/firmware/misc_mdm/image/dbl.mbn /vendor/firmware/dbl.mbn
```

So how does the tombstones works?? I'm a little confused here.